# Export battery usage report

Tags: iphone, battery

Is it there any tool that I can use in order to export the battery usage from my iPhone SE?

The device is running iOS 13.2.2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a screen shot while viewing the report.

Comment: I need something more technical and detailed.